# Clojure: Accessing Unique Field of a Datatype Directly

Tags: data-structures, types, clojure

Suppose I have a datatype with only one field that holds a sorted map.

```
(defrecord AdjacencyList [data])
(def adjacency-list (AdjacencyList. (sorted-map 1 {2 100}, 2 {3 -100})))
```

Now, if I want to manipulate the field and keep its type I must do something like this:

```
(AdjacencyList. (dissoc (:data adjacency-list) 2))
```

Is there a way to reference the field by calling the record?

```
(dissoc adjacency-list 2)
```

If I needed a regular hash map I could use the record's map implementation but I need a sorted map and I got other similar datatypes using sets and vectors.

A solution would be to use deftype instead and implement the required data structures myself, but I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The record is a single field, right? Is there a reason you're not using the sorted map directly? Is it a polymorphism thing?

Comment: @beyamor That's right, it's a single field and I'm implementing a protocol.

Comment: Is it your protocol, or somebody else's? If yours, you might consider putting type info into meta data, and using a multi-method instead.

Comment: @Chouser It's my protocol, I want some conversion functions to react differently whether the Adjacency List includes weights or not. I will go with this option. The performance improvements of using protocols over multimethods are meager in this scenario. Would you update your answer so I can solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure's update-in function works on all kinds of associative collections including sorted maps and defrecords:

(update-in adjacency-list [:data] dissoc 2)

Comment: I guess I could wrap update-in in a function/macro and assume all my single fields are called "data". Another thing is that I'm trying too hard to maintain the type along a function. I could just destructure :data as a function parameter and only convert it to a datatype again if and when the function returns it or passes it to another function. However, that's another ball to keep juggling in your mind.